# Material UI React TextField height isn't rendered properly

Tags: reactjs, web, material-ui, textfield

I got a bit of an issue with material-UI in react. I was trying to use the TextField component. I copied and pasted the same code as it is on the website. However, it doesn't display the correct height

Packages version:

- "@material-ui/core": "^4.7.0"
- "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1"

[image: screenshot of incorrect rendering]

Comment: Hi Felix, welcome to StackOverflow! Please add more details about what version of Material-ui are you using.

Comment: Have you tried it recently? https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/

Comment: I'm using:

"@material-ui/core": "^4.7.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",

Yes, i just tried it before i posted this.

Comment: Please include in your question text the exact code that you copied. There are many `TextField` demos on the website. Do you have any additional code other than the code you copied (e.g. any global CSS that might be affecting the Material-UI components)?

Comment: If you are using any sort of CSS resets on your app they may conflict with Material-UI's styles and cause issues like this. I would recommend removing them if so and replacing them with Materials "CSS Baseline" component: https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/